# Using Visual Studio Online (VSO) without Visual Studio

Tags: project-management, azure-devops, alm

I would like to use VSO as App life cycle management (ALM) tool for other platforms, native android development to be specific. I understand that I can use it for sprint planning and related things.

**However, I would like to associate my checkins with BLIs/Tasks/Features.**

I think if its achievable then raising pull requests should be as per flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for you to associate checkins with Tasks or Features work items.

You can do it via opening the work item in IE, and go to All Links tab, select LinkTo and choose Changeset link type. See:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for tip! Its indeed a way to achieve this and certainly helpful, I liked the way its integrated in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Git repositories in Visual Studio Online, work items are linked to commits by using the notation `#1234` using the work item number.  The server will see it and automatically associate the work item with ID of 1234 to that commit and use it in other locations like builds, pull requests, etc.

We call the feature "#mention" and you can see more information about it here:  https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2015-jun-3-vso.aspx

[image: #mention in Visual Studio Online and Team Foundation Server]